Intune error 0x87d1fde8 when attempting to disable Copilot with TurnOffWindowsCopilot
Microsoft's CSP documentation for disabling Copilot states the following OMA URI and an integer value of 1 to disable Copilot on Windows 11:
./User/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/WindowsAI/TurnOffWindowsCopilot
Unfortunately on all our existing machines, it fails with the error code 0x87d1fde8:

All machines are running 10.0.22631.3447 which is newer than the minimum requirement stated in the CSP.
There is one machine it has succeeded on, and it was a machine that was provisioned since the policy was added to Intune.
Anyone had this problem and been able to resolve it?
